# how can i display active route name in text reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

i tried like ${route} but to be honest i have no idea.
i want to put some helpful links bottom of website and it must show active links name to belong links

```
import React from 'react'
    import './Links.css';
    function Links() {
        return (
            <div>
                  <div className="links_person">
                      <div className="links_right_2">
                        <div className="links_right_cild_2">
                          <span className="links_span">  You can take look and learn more 
                             about ${route}
                         </span> 
                            
                     </div>
                  </div>
    
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default Links
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check current route by using  useLocation from react-router-dom
something like this

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import React from 'react';
import './Links.css';

function Links() {
  const location = useLocation();
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="links_person">
        <div className="links_right_2">
          <div className="links_right_cild_2">
            <span className="links_span">
              You can take look and learn more about : {location.pathname}
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @hilmi if this help you please upvote my ans